# DocumentFormat.openxml doesn't seems to be working with Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, openxml-sdk

I have been trying to intergrate the openxml package in Azure function. The code compiles fine but when i try to reach the function url it doesn't downloads the file but fails the call and there is no execution error in the code.

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, [Inject]TrainingManager trainingManager)
    {

        //dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
        //string trainingCourseId = data?.trainingCourseId;
        log.Info("Function App Started");
        HttpResponseMessage response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Create Document
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
            {
                // Add a main document part. 
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

                // Create the document structure and add some text.
                mainPart.Document = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document();
                Body docBody = new Body();

                // Add your docx content here
                Paragraph para = docBody.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
                Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
                run.AppendChild(new Text("Hi"));

                mainPart.Document.Save();
            }
            mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(mem);

        }

        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "AttendanceList.docx"
        };
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/msword");

        log.Info("Sending Response");
        return response;
    }
```

Let me know if anyone has faced this issue or have a solution to it.

Here is what i see in network tab[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTyAs.png)
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you tried adding a `try .. catch`? What about running it locally and debugging? We're gonna need some more information to be able to help you.

Comment: @rickvdbosch It not throwing any error during the execution of code and it reaches till the end of the last line. When I see the network call, it says 'failed'. I think it is not able to download the file.

Comment: Which status code does the call have? Have you debugged? Looked into variables that _should_ hold specific types of data to check if they _do_?

Comment: @rickvdbosch I have debugged, there is no error in the code. I see a 'failed' status code in network tab.

Comment: My best guess based on the little information we get is your request is timing out. The image you provided shows the time for the request is 1.6 minutes. I would look into that. By the way, if you _click_ the failed request, it gives you more information like Headers.

Comment: @rickvdbosch The time is high beacuse i was debugging the code. I have tried to save the file also in file system and it worked well fine in file system.
but seems like there is a issue with the downloading the file.

Comment: @rickvdbosch header image added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195918/discussion-between-rocket-singh-and-rickvdbosch).

Comment: what happened when you attempted the suggestion with removing `using` from `MemoryStream` ?